# remove repeating characters and put at the end of the string in c++

Tags: c++, string

i am trying to inplement the titled in c++ but didn't figure out 
 here is what i tried

```
char *str=new char[100];
cout<<"enter the string";
cin.getline(str,100);
int len=strlen(str);
int i=0;
//iterating through the string
while(i<len-1)
{
    int signal=0;
    char x;
    int j=i+1;
    while(j<len)
    {
        if(str[j]==str[i])
        {
            x=str[i];
            for(int k=j;k<len;k++)
            {
                str[k]=str[k+1];
            }
            len--;
            signal=1;
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
        }
    }
    if(signal==1)
    {
        for(int l=i;l<len;l++)
        {
            str[l]=str[l+1];
        }
        str[len-1]=x;
    }
}
cout<<str;
```

in this code i have not done i++, please tell me where to do i++
or you can tell an easy and simple code to achieve that.

thnx for your time.

Comment: What do *repeated characters* mean? Two consecutive characters that have the same value? A character that already appeared anywhere in the string before? Do you need to keep them? Do you need to maintain the relative position of those?

Comment: @chris will it make any change to the functionality?

Comment: @bhawin, It integrates pretty well into C strings and it's definitely safer and easier.

Comment: @david eg. "darren" is the input string , then "daenr" should be output

Comment: @bhawin: What about "roadshow"? Will that be left as it is, or transformed into "radshwo"? Take the time to specify the problem completely, and provide examples that clarify any potential uses.

Answer (score 1):

Using std::string is easier:

```
     std::string input("Darren");
     std::string uniqueCharsString, repeatedCharsString;

     for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i)
     {
        // If we are looking at the last character, we need to compare it with the previous one
        if (i == input.length() - 1)
        {
           // If the character is the same as the previous one, add it to the repeatedCharsString
           if (input.at(i) == input.at(i-1))
              repeatedCharsString.push_back(input.at(i));
           // If the character is not the same as the previous one, add it to the uniqueCharsString
           else
              uniqueCharsString.push_back(input.at(i));
        }
        // If the character is the same as the following one, add it to the repeatedCharsString
        else if (input.at(i) == input.at(i+1))
        {
           repeatedCharsString.push_back(input.at(i));
           // Skip the next character since we already know it's the same as the previous one
           i++;
        }
        // If the character is not the same as the following one, add it to the uniqueCharsString
        else
           uniqueCharsString.push_back(input.at(i));
     }
     std::string result(uniqueCharsString + repeatedCharsString);
```

The string comparison is case sensitive.

Hope this helps!